# Python Unittest: How to initialize selenium in a class and avoid having the browser opening twice?

Tags: python, selenium, python-unittest

Consider the example below, since I'm initializing the driver in `setUp` method and using it in `test_login`, the browser will open twice, the first time during `setUp` and then it will be closed and the tests will begin.

If I remove the logic from `setUp` and put it in `test_login`, the driver will be undefined in `test_profile` and `tearDown`

What's the correct way to initialize the driver and use it throughout the class while not causing the browser to open twice?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
        self.driver.get('https://example.com/login')
        self.current_url = self.driver.current_url
        self.dashboard_url = 'https://example.com/dashboard'

    def test_login(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.dashboard_url, self.current_url)
    
    def test_profile(self):
        self.driver.get('https://example.com/profile')
    
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [setUpClass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) / [tearDownClass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDownClass):

```
import unittest


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        print('setUpClass')

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls) -> None:
        print('tearDownClass')

    def setUp(self):
        print('setUp')

    def test_login(self):
        print('login')

    def test_profile(self):
        print('profile')

    def tearDown(self):
        print('tearDown')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that uses `unittest.TestCase` with Selenium. It has the `setUp()` and `tearDown()` steps, and it gets the desired behavior you're looking for, although probably with more than you asked for.

You can run it with `python -m unittest`:

```py
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from unittest import TestCase

class RefinedRawSelenium(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = None
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        if "linux" in sys.platform:
            options.add_argument("--headless=new")
        options.add_experimental_option(
            "excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"],
        )
        prefs = {
            "credentials_enable_service": False,
            "profile.password_manager_enabled": False,
        }
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def tearDown(self):
        if self.driver:
            try:
                if self.driver.service.process:
                    self.driver.quit()
            except Exception:
                pass

    def wait_for_element_visible(
        self, selector, by="css selector", timeout=10
    ):
        try:
            return WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((by, selector))
            )
        except Exception:
            raise Exception(
                "Element {%s} was not visible after %s seconds!"
                % (selector, timeout)
            )

    def wait_for_element_clickable(
        self, selector, by="css selector", timeout=10
    ):
        try:
            return WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, selector))
            )
        except Exception:
            raise Exception(
                "Element {%s} was not visible/clickable after %s seconds!"
                % (selector, timeout)
            )

    def wait_for_element_not_visible(
        self, selector, by="css selector", timeout=10
    ):
        try:
            return WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(
                EC.invisibility_of_element((by, selector))
            )
        except Exception:
            raise Exception(
                "Element {%s} was still visible after %s seconds!"
                % (selector, timeout)
            )

    def open(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)

    def click(self, selector, by="css selector", timeout=7):
        el = self.wait_for_element_clickable(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)
        el.click()

    def type(self, selector, text, by="css selector", timeout=10):
        el = self.wait_for_element_clickable(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)
        el.clear()
        if not text.endswith("\n"):
            el.send_keys(text)
        else:
            el.send_keys(text[:-1])
            el.submit()

    def assert_element(self, selector, by="css selector", timeout=7):
        self.wait_for_element_visible(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)

    def assert_text(self, text, selector="html", by="css selector", timeout=7):
        el = self.wait_for_element_visible(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)
        self.assertIn(text, el.text)

    def assert_exact_text(self, text, selector, by="css selector", timeout=7):
        el = self.wait_for_element_visible(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)
        self.assertEqual(text, el.text)

    def assert_element_not_visible(
        self, selector, by="css selector", timeout=7
    ):
        self.wait_for_element_not_visible(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)

    def test_add_item_to_cart(self):
        self.open("https://www.saucedemo.com")
        self.type("#user-name", "standard_user")
        self.type("#password", "secret_sauce\n")
        self.assert_element("div.inventory_list")
        self.assert_text("PRODUCTS", "span.title")
        self.click('button[name*="backpack"]')
        self.click("#shopping_cart_container a")
        self.assert_exact_text("YOUR CART", "span.title")
        self.assert_text("Backpack", "div.cart_item")
        self.click("#remove-sauce-labs-backpack")
        self.assert_element_not_visible("div.cart_item")
        self.click("#react-burger-menu-btn")
        self.click("a#logout_sidebar_link")
        self.assert_element("input#login-button")

# When run with "python" instead of "pytest" or "python -m unittest"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from unittest import main
    main()
```

That was taken from my example in [SeleniumBase/examples/migration/raw_selenium/refined_raw.py](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/migration/raw_selenium/refined_raw.py)

It'll actually be part of my session at SeleniumConf 2023 this year (https://seleniumconf.com/agenda/#python-selenium-fundamentals-to-frameworks-with-seleniumbase), where I'll be demoing how to simplify that to something like this, which uses `unittest.TestCase` behind the scenes in an import:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class CleanSeleniumBase(BaseCase):
    def test_add_item_to_cart(self):
        self.open("https://www.saucedemo.com")
        self.type("#user-name", "standard_user")
        self.type("#password", "secret_sauce\n")
        self.assert_element("div.inventory_list")
        self.assert_text("PRODUCTS", "span.title")
        self.click('button[name*="backpack"]')
        self.click("#shopping_cart_container a")
        self.assert_exact_text("YOUR CART", "span.title")
        self.assert_text("Backpack", "div.cart_item")
        self.click("#remove-sauce-labs-backpack")
        self.assert_element_not_visible("div.cart_item")
        self.click("#react-burger-menu-btn")
        self.click("a#logout_sidebar_link")
        self.assert_element("input#login-button")

# When run with "python" instead of "pytest"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pytest import main
    main([__file__, "-s"])
```

(That one uses `seleniumbase.BaseCase`, which inherits `unittest.TestCase`. Example from [SeleniumBase/examples/migration/raw_selenium/simple_sbase.py](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/migration/raw_selenium/simple_sbase.py))

Comment: Although its a nice example but does not really answer the question asked. You use  chrome in headless mode whereas the question asks that the browser should not be opened twice but just once.

Comment: It answers multiple questions around ``unittest.TestCase``, including the one asked. It shows proper ``setUp()``, which will spin up the browser once. And it shows you how to build a complete framework around Selenium for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine. Please add the decorator `@classmethod` before the setUp and tearDown methods.
Also, issue is with the line `self.driver.get('https://example.com/login')` in the setUp method. Just remove it from there and maybe create a new function to hold that code.

Comment: I also had to rename them to setUpClass / tearDownClass